# Accessing the return value of a ruby script in shell

Tags: ruby, shell, ssh, terminal

How do I access the value of variable `a` in `test1.rb` to use further in `test1.rb` outside `SSH`?

In `test1.rb`

```
Net::SSH.start("host", ava) do |ssh|
   ssh.exec('ruby test2.rb')
end
```

In `host`, `test2.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Value
  def get_value()
    a = 1 + 2
  end
end

v = Value.new
v.get_value()
```

Comment: Just write `puts v.get_value()`.

Comment: You can set a return code with exit: `exit v.get_value()`

Comment: I want to use the value of a in rest of test1.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test1.rb script you need to pass a block to the `ssh.exec` method and in that block you will be able to access anything you `puts` from test2.rb

```
Net::SSH.start("127.0.0.1", 'ava', password: '') do |ssh|
  ssh.exec('ruby test2.rb') do |channel, stream, data|
    puts "got: #{data}" if stream == :stdout
  end
end
```

`puts` the value you want to pass to test1.rb from test2.rb:

```
v = Value.new
puts v.get_value()
```

That will send the value to stdout

More info in the readme: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh#readme